# Half speed scrubbing for UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

I'm making my own slider that is subclass of UIControl and I'd like to make half-spped scrubbing just like on default iOS AVPlayerViewController
[image]
So how to make half-speed scrubbing on UIControl ?

here is my touch processing:

```
override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    super.beginTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
    return true
}

override func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    super.continueTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
    let lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
    self.moveThumb(lastPoint)
    return true
}

override func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.endTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
}
```

Comment: …what's your question?

Comment: @AaronBrager added question to my post :)